# Flux: How to get the last record for each value

Tags: flux, influxdb-2

Ok this have to be something easy, but I can not find out.

Y have the following table, obtained with flux:

[image: table]

Ok, I am monitoring Jira, and as you see, in the column "event_type" I have the creation and the following jiras updates.
The target here is get the newest record from each "_value" column, I mean, each jira

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first need to `group` by value and then just get `last`

```
|> group(columns: ["_value"])
|> last()
```